# What happens to Firebase local data if app crashes/closes without internet?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm writing an Android app in Java and using Firebase Realtime Database for the first time.  The likelihood that users will enter a bunch of data without having any internet is very high.

So, what happens to that data if the app quits/crashes prior to having an internet connection?

Is that data all lost?  Should I write all of that to persistent storage (sharedpreferences)?  I have to admit, one of the major reasons I was trying Firebase was to avoid having to manage the data myself, but I can't afford to lose anything.

Comment: Firebase consists of 18 products, and they're all different in this respect. Which one(s) are you asking about?

Comment: Just search for whatever Firebase tool you are using + "offline access" to find out. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely asking about one of Firebase's databases: Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database. While they are quite different when it comes to how they persist local writes, their behavior is common enough to start with a baseline.

---

The database client that runs in your app keeps a queue in its local cache of pending writes: writes that are applied locally, but have not yet been applied on the server.

For *Cloud Firestore*, this queue of pending writes is always kept on the local disk of the device. So when the app restarts, it'll read the queue and try to synchronize them with the server again.

For *Realtime Database* it (by default) is only kept in memory, so you'll lose it on a crash/restart. You can tell the Realtime Database to store both data it's recently read, and the queue of pending writes, in a disk cache by [enabling its disk persistence layer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence). In that case, the behavior on restart is the same as above:  the client reads the queue of pending writes and tries to synchronize them with the server.